# "From Scratch" Neural Network Weight Adjustment Not Working

Tags: python, neural-network

I have been working to create this neural network in my free time over the past couple of weeks; I have been feeding it two numbers (1s or 0s) and getting it to learn the XOR function. However, after many different debugging attempts, I have run into a problem with the part of my program in which I adjust the weight of nodes and connections according to whether the output was too big or too small.
When the Output is stated to be "Too Big", and connector values are at 1, then these values will not change; the same goes for "Too small" Outputs: they will not increase connector values that are -1.
Below is the complete code; after that, I have cut out the weight adjustment code so it is easier to look through.
The code is ~150 lines long, so I'm not expecting a solution anytime soon, but any help would be much appreciated.

My question is: is there anything wrong with this section of coding that I have overlooked, or do you maybe have a fix?

Thanks!

Code:

```
import random
from random import randint
GenericArray = [-1,-0.9,-0.8,-0.7,-0.6,-0.5,-0.4,-0.3,-0.2,-0.1,0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1]
Another_Generic_Array = [-0.1,0.1]
Node1_Value = 0
Node2_Value = 0
Output = 0
Generic_Variable = 0
NumberOfQuestions = 0
QuestionsRight = 0
Randomnumber = random.choice(GenericArray)
Connector1_1 = Randomnumber
Randomnumber = random.choice(GenericArray)
Connector1_2 = Randomnumber
Randomnumber = random.choice(GenericArray)
Connector2_1 = Randomnumber
Randomnumber = random.choice(GenericArray)
Connector2_2 = Randomnumber
Randomnumber = random.choice(GenericArray)
Node1 = Randomnumber
Randomnumber = random.choice(GenericArray)
Node2 = Randomnumber
Randomnumber = random.choice(GenericArray)
ConnectorNd1_Out = Randomnumber
Randomnumber = random.choice(GenericArray)
ConnectorNd2_Out = Randomnumber
Decision = "Null"
Spam = 2
i = 0
while True:
    if Generic_Variable == 0:
        print("ERROR")
    i = 0
    InputNumber = input("How many numbers do you want inputted?")
    while True:
        if Connector1_1 == 0:
            Connector1_1 = random.choice(Another_Generic_Array)
        if Connector1_2 == 0:
            Connector1_2 = random.choice(Another_Generic_Array)
        if Connector2_1 == 0:
            Connector2_1 = random.choice(Another_Generic_Array)
        if Connector2_2 == 0:
            Connector2_2 = random.choice(Another_Generic_Array)
        if Node1 == 0:
            Node1 = random.choice(Another_Generic_Array)
        if Node2 == 0:
            Node2 = random.choice(Another_Generic_Array)
        if ConnectorNd1_Out == 0:
            ConnectorNd1_Out = random.choice(Another_Generic_Array)
        if ConnectorNd2_Out == 0:
            ConnectorNd2_Out = random.choice(Another_Generic_Array)
        if Connector1_1 > 1:
            Connector1_1 = 1
        if Connector1_2 > 1:
            Connector1_2 = 1
        if Connector2_1 > 1:
            Connector2_1 = 1
        if Connector2_2 > 1:
            Connector2_2 = 1
        if Node1 > 1:
            Node1 = 1
        if Node2 > 1:
            Node2 = 1
        if ConnectorNd1_Out > 1:
            ConnectorNd1_Out = 1
        if ConnectorNd2_Out > 1:
            ConnectorNd2_Out = 1
        if Connector1_1 < -1:
            Connector1_1 = -1
        if Connector1_2 < -1:
            Connector1_2 = -1
        if Connector2_1 < -1:
            Connector2_1 = -1
        if Connector2_2 < -1:
            Connector2_2 = -1
        if Node1 < -1:
            Node1 = -1
        if Node2 < -1:
            Node2 = -1
        if ConnectorNd1_Out < -1:
            ConnectorNd1_Out = -1
        if ConnectorNd2_Out < -1:
            ConnectorNd2_Out = -1
        Input1 = randint(0,1)
        Input2 = randint(0,1)
        Node1_Value = (Input1 * Connector1_1) + (Input2 * Connector2_1)
        Node2_Value = (Input1 * Connector1_2) + (Input2 * Connector2_2)
        Output = (Node1_Value * Node1 * ConnectorNd1_Out) + (Node2_Value * Node2 * ConnectorNd2_Out)
        print Connector1_1
        print Connector1_2
        print Connector2_1
        print Connector2_2
        print ConnectorNd1_Out
        print ConnectorNd2_Out
        print Node1
        print Node2
        if Output == Input1 ^ Input2:
            print("The Output was correct")
            QuestionsRight += 1
            NumberOfQuestions += 1
            PercentageCorrect = (QuestionsRight / NumberOfQuestions) * 100
        elif Output > Input1 ^ Input2:
            print("The Output was too big")
            Generic_Variable = (Input1 ^ Input2) - Output
            Generic_Variable = 1 / Generic_Variable
            Generic_Variable = 1 - Generic_Variable
            if Connector1_1 > 0:
                Connector1_1 = Connector1_1 - (Generic_Variable * Connector1_1)
            if Connector1_2 > 0:
                Connector1_2 = Connector1_2 - (Generic_Variable * Connector1_2)
            if Connector2_1 > 0:
                Connector2_1 = Connector2_1 - (Generic_Variable * Connector2_1)
            if Connector2_2 > 0:
                Connector2_2 = Connector2_2 - (Generic_Variable * Connector2_2)
            if ConnectorNd1_Out > 0:
                ConnectorNd1_Out = ConnectorNd1_Out - (Generic_Variable * ConnectorNd1_Out)
            if ConnectorNd2_Out > 0:
                ConnectorNd2_Out = ConnectorNd2_Out - (Generic_Variable * ConnectorNd2_Out)
            if Node1 > 0:
                Node1 = Node1 - (Generic_Variable * Node1)
            if Node2 > 0:
                Node2 = Node2 - (Generic_Variable * Node2)
            if Connector1_1 < 0:
                Connector1_1 = Connector1_1 + (Generic_Variable * (0 - Connector1_1))
            if Connector1_2 < 0:
                Connector1_2 = Connector1_2 + (Generic_Variable * (0 - Connector1_2))
            if Connector2_1 < 0:
                Connector2_1 = Connector2_1 + (Generic_Variable * (0 - Connector2_1))
            if Connector2_2 < 0:
                Connector2_2 = Connector2_2 + (Generic_Variable * (0 - Connector2_2))
            if ConnectorNd1_Out < 0:
                ConnectorNd1_Out = ConnectorNd1_Out + (Generic_Variable * (0 - ConnectorNd1_Out))
            if ConnectorNd2_Out < 0:
                ConnectorNd2_Out = ConnectorNd2_Out + (Generic_Variable * (0 - ConnectorNd2_Out))
            if Node1 < 0:
                Node1 = Node1 + (Generic_Variable * (0 - Node1))
            if Node2 < 0:
                Node2 = Node2 + (Generic_Variable * (0 - Node2))
            NumberOfQuestions += 1
            PercentageCorrect = (QuestionsRight / NumberOfQuestions) * 100
        elif Output < Input1 ^ Input2:
            print("The Output was too small")
            Generic_Variable = (Input1 ^ Input2) - Output
            Generic_Variable = 1 / Generic_Variable
            Generic_Variable = 1 - Generic_Variable
            if Connector1_1 > 0:
                Connector1_1 = Connector1_1 - (Generic_Variable * Connector1_1)
            if Connector1_2 > 0:
                Connector1_2 = Connector1_2 - (Generic_Variable * Connector1_2)
            if Connector2_1 > 0:
                Connector2_1 = Connector2_1 - (Generic_Variable * Connector2_1)
            if Connector2_2 > 0:
                Connector2_2 = Connector2_2 - (Generic_Variable * Connector2_2)
            if ConnectorNd1_Out > 0:
                ConnectorNd1_Out = ConnectorNd1_Out - (Generic_Variable * ConnectorNd1_Out)
            if ConnectorNd2_Out > 0:
                ConnectorNd2_Out = ConnectorNd2_Out - (Generic_Variable * ConnectorNd2_Out)
            if Node1 > 0:
                Node1 = Node1 - (Generic_Variable * Node1)
            if Node2 > 0:
                Node2 = Node2 - (Generic_Variable * Node2)
            if Connector1_1 < 0:
                Connector1_1 = Connector1_1 + (Generic_Variable * (0 - Connector1_1))
            if Connector1_2 < 0:
                Connector1_2 = Connector1_2 + (Generic_Variable * (0 - Connector1_2))
            if Connector2_1 < 0:
                Connector2_1 = Connector2_1 + (Generic_Variable * (0 - Connector2_1))
            if Connector2_2 < 0:
                Connector2_2 = Connector2_2 + (Generic_Variable * (0 - Connector2_2))
            if ConnectorNd1_Out < 0:
                ConnectorNd1_Out = ConnectorNd1_Out + (Generic_Variable * (0 - ConnectorNd1_Out))
            if ConnectorNd2_Out < 0:
                ConnectorNd2_Out = ConnectorNd2_Out + (Generic_Variable * (0 - ConnectorNd2_Out))
            if Node1 < 0:
                Node1 = Node1 + (Generic_Variable * (0 - Node1))
            if Node2 < 0:
                Node2 = Node2 + (Generic_Variable * (0 - Node2))
            NumberOfQuestions += 1
            PercentageCorrect = ((QuestionsRight * 100) / NumberOfQuestions)
        round(Connector1_1, 2)
        round(Connector1_2, 2)
        round(Connector2_1, 2)
        round(Connector2_2, 2)
        round(ConnectorNd1_Out, 2)
        round(ConnectorNd2_Out, 2)
        round(Node1, 2)
        round(Node2, 2)
        i = i+1
        if i == InputNumber:
            print("We've had " + str(NumberOfQuestions) + " questions asked.")
            print(str(QuestionsRight) + " of them were answered correctly.")
            break
    raw_input = ("Training finished!")
```

Weight Adjustment Segment:

```
elif Output > Input1 ^ Input2:
            print("The Output was too big")
            Generic_Variable = (Input1 ^ Input2) - Output
            Generic_Variable = 1 / Generic_Variable
            Generic_Variable = 1 - Generic_Variable
            if Connector1_1 > 0:
                Connector1_1 = Connector1_1 - (Generic_Variable * Connector1_1)
            if Connector1_2 > 0:
                Connector1_2 = Connector1_2 - (Generic_Variable * Connector1_2)
            if Connector2_1 > 0:
                Connector2_1 = Connector2_1 - (Generic_Variable * Connector2_1)
            if Connector2_2 > 0:
                Connector2_2 = Connector2_2 - (Generic_Variable * Connector2_2)
            if ConnectorNd1_Out > 0:
                ConnectorNd1_Out = ConnectorNd1_Out - (Generic_Variable * ConnectorNd1_Out)
            if ConnectorNd2_Out > 0:
                ConnectorNd2_Out = ConnectorNd2_Out - (Generic_Variable * ConnectorNd2_Out)
            if Node1 > 0:
                Node1 = Node1 - (Generic_Variable * Node1)
            if Node2 > 0:
                Node2 = Node2 - (Generic_Variable * Node2)
            if Connector1_1 < 0:
                Connector1_1 = Connector1_1 + (Generic_Variable * (0 - Connector1_1))
            if Connector1_2 < 0:
                Connector1_2 = Connector1_2 + (Generic_Variable * (0 - Connector1_2))
            if Connector2_1 < 0:
                Connector2_1 = Connector2_1 + (Generic_Variable * (0 - Connector2_1))
            if Connector2_2 < 0:
                Connector2_2 = Connector2_2 + (Generic_Variable * (0 - Connector2_2))
            if ConnectorNd1_Out < 0:
                ConnectorNd1_Out = ConnectorNd1_Out + (Generic_Variable * (0 - ConnectorNd1_Out))
            if ConnectorNd2_Out < 0:
                ConnectorNd2_Out = ConnectorNd2_Out + (Generic_Variable * (0 - ConnectorNd2_Out))
            if Node1 < 0:
                Node1 = Node1 + (Generic_Variable * (0 - Node1))
            if Node2 < 0:
                Node2 = Node2 + (Generic_Variable * (0 - Node2))
            NumberOfQuestions += 1
            PercentageCorrect = (QuestionsRight / NumberOfQuestions) * 100
        elif Output < Input1 ^ Input2:
            print("The Output was too small")
            Generic_Variable = (Input1 ^ Input2) - Output
            Generic_Variable = 1 / Generic_Variable
            Generic_Variable = 1 - Generic_Variable
            if Connector1_1 > 0:
                Connector1_1 = Connector1_1 - (Generic_Variable * Connector1_1)
            if Connector1_2 > 0:
                Connector1_2 = Connector1_2 - (Generic_Variable * Connector1_2)
            if Connector2_1 > 0:
                Connector2_1 = Connector2_1 - (Generic_Variable * Connector2_1)
            if Connector2_2 > 0:
                Connector2_2 = Connector2_2 - (Generic_Variable * Connector2_2)
            if ConnectorNd1_Out > 0:
                ConnectorNd1_Out = ConnectorNd1_Out - (Generic_Variable * ConnectorNd1_Out)
            if ConnectorNd2_Out > 0:
                ConnectorNd2_Out = ConnectorNd2_Out - (Generic_Variable * ConnectorNd2_Out)
            if Node1 > 0:
                Node1 = Node1 - (Generic_Variable * Node1)
            if Node2 > 0:
                Node2 = Node2 - (Generic_Variable * Node2)
            if Connector1_1 < 0:
                Connector1_1 = Connector1_1 + (Generic_Variable * (0 - Connector1_1))
            if Connector1_2 < 0:
                Connector1_2 = Connector1_2 + (Generic_Variable * (0 - Connector1_2))
            if Connector2_1 < 0:
                Connector2_1 = Connector2_1 + (Generic_Variable * (0 - Connector2_1))
            if Connector2_2 < 0:
                Connector2_2 = Connector2_2 + (Generic_Variable * (0 - Connector2_2))
            if ConnectorNd1_Out < 0:
                ConnectorNd1_Out = ConnectorNd1_Out + (Generic_Variable * (0 - ConnectorNd1_Out))
            if ConnectorNd2_Out < 0:
                ConnectorNd2_Out = ConnectorNd2_Out + (Generic_Variable * (0 - ConnectorNd2_Out))
            if Node1 < 0:
                Node1 = Node1 + (Generic_Variable * (0 - Node1))
            if Node2 < 0:
                Node2 = Node2 + (Generic_Variable * (0 - Node2))
```

Comment: Apologies if the code is a bit messy! I'm quite new to Python, and have been mainly self taught.

Comment: “Not working” is not a problem description *I* could do a lot with. Please be more specific. Btw, is this an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: You need to learn about lists. That will help you get rid of those `Connector_i_j` variables that clutter your code

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying the question! That was a mistake.

Comment: The Fact is, When an output is too big, and the Connector variables are at  1, they will not decrease in value, and the same goes for values of -1 when the output is too small!

Comment: My question has now been edited to include the ACTUAL question. Apologies.